# Django: forms.MultipleChoiceField Not Displayed

Tags: python, django, django-forms, multi-select

I am a beginner in Django/Python. Am having problem with djangos MultipleChoiceField in that it is not been displayed both in the loaded HTML in the browser and the page being displayed. The other aspects of the form such as my email field are been rendered successfully.

forms.py

```
class CustomSetForm(forms.Form):
choice = ()

def __init__(self, qs, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    requirements = qs.required
    self.choice = list(requirements.split(','))
    print(self.choice)

email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-group form-control input-lg ', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), )
qualifications = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           choices=choice)
```

views.py

```
def get_job_requirements(request, *args, **kwargs):
selected_job_title = kwargs.get('job_title')
obj_model = Author.objects.get(job_title=selected_job_title)
form = CustomSetForm(obj_model)
context = {'form': form}
try:
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            job_title_obj = Author.objects.get(job_title=selected_job_title)
            qualifications = form.cleaned_data.get('qualifications')
            applicant = Applicants.objects.create(email=email, job_title=job_title_obj,
                                                  qualifications=qualifications)
            applicant.save()
            return JsonResponse({'created': True})
        return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
```

My Html

```
 <form method="post" id="application-form">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ form.email }}
                {{ form.qualifications.as_p }}


                <div class="bg-light row" >
                    <div class="" id="btn-box">
                        <div class="col-md-12 d-grid gap-2 col-6 ">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

HTML in browser

```
<form method="post" id="application-form">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="og1mWWpCR6rwxOw19fhUp4jX4KfFqbmeczbTwO92zNYtXBoESiZbi5biugeOj8N0">

                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-group form-control input-lg " placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_email">
                


                <div class="bg-light row">
                    <div class="" id="btn-box">
                        <div class="col-md-12 d-grid gap-2 col-6 ">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Updated forms.py

```
class CustomSetForm(forms.Form):
choice = (
    ("1", "Austria"),
    ("2", "Germany"),
    ("3", "Netherlands"),
)

email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-group form-control input-lg ', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), )
qualifications = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           choices=choice)
```

**Update**
I changed `{{ form.qualifications.as_p }}` to `{{ form.qualifications}}` and got the following in my browser `<django.forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple object at 0x0000018512709870>`

Comment: the problem might be because `choice= ()  is empty` when you print `choice` are you getting some data ? if you know that data is from a model you can use `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: When I print choice i get the following  ['Grade 12 Certificate', ' Degree in a Related Field', ' Minimum 3 years working experience']

Comment: and not that `choice should be a tuple something like choice = (("1","good"),("2","bad"))` and you in your case you have a list change that.

Comment: Try to change your list to tuple it should work.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow i have changed it to a tuple and updated my code above. Unfortunately its still not working

Comment: try to put the choice outside the form like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets

Comment: I have removed the `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` and put the `choice` outside the class definition. Its still not been displayed

Comment: interesting i am sorry that i am not able to help.because everything i told you is from the official documentation try also to change this `{{ form.qualifications.as_p }}` to `{{ form.qualifications }}`

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow I have changed it to `{{ form.qualifications }}` and this `<django.forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple object at 0x0000018512709870> ` got displayed in the browser. And thanks so much for your help.

Comment: amazing i am happy i was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I managed to solve the problem. I did this by changing from a `MultipleChoiceField` to a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with some help from this article:
https://medium.com/swlh/django-forms-for-many-to-many-fields-d977dec4b024

**Updated forms.py**:

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-group form-control input-lg ', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), )
required = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Requirements.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

class Meta:
    model = Requirements
    fields = ['email', 'required']
```

**Updated views.py**:

```
def application_form(request):
try:
    form = ApplicationForm()
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'created': True})
    return JsonResponse(form.errors.as_json(), safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

form = ApplicationForm(request.POST or None)
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
```